# Play Framework 2.1.3 bash cursor gone after console crashes

Tags: playframework-2.0

I sometimes run into a problem where my playframework server crashes with an output of:

```
Killed
```

Then I'm thrown out to the bash shell (on ubuntu server). Now the cursor is gone, and nothing is printed as I type. I still can run commands, and the results of commands are shown, just not what I type etc.

I'm running in dev mode, so I don't expect it to be super stable, since it's reloading the app quite often. But it's annoying when I lose the ability to see what I type in bash.

This generally leads me to have to kill the screen window, create a new one, set it's name, and put it in the correct window order. I have several windows with explicit names so, it's an annoyance.

Would be glad for any help on how I can prevent a crashing Play console to swallow cursor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens to me time to time as well. Try typing in reset and hit enter. It will re-initialize your terminal again.